# Finding column space - why does this algorithm work?

Tags: linear-algebra

When I want to find the column space of a matrix, I can row reduce it to echelon form and choose only the columns corresponding to the columns without the free variables in the reduced row echelon form matrix. I have proved it mathematically, but I fail to see why does it work intuitively? Is there any intuition to why that happens or can it only be seen with a rigorous proof? The linearly independence is intuitive, but the fact that these columns span the column space is far from intuitive for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Consider for example

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 6 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 6 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\textrm{row reduce}} R = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

The basic property of row reduction is that $Ax = 0$ iff $Rx = 0$ (the solution space stays the same). You can look at this property in terms of columns: If we write $A = (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ and $R = (r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)$ where $a_i$ are the columns of $A$ and $r_i$ are the columns of $R$ then

$$ A \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix} = x_1 a_1 + x_2 a_2 + x_3 a_3 + x_4 a_4 = 0 \iff R \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix} = a_1 r_1 + a_2 r_2 + a_3 r_3 + a_4 r_4 = 0. $$

That is, any linear dependence which is satisfied by the columns of $A$ must be satisfied by the columns of $R$ and vice versa. So let's say that you want to find the column space of $A$. You look instead at $R$ and see immediately that $r_1,r_2,r_4$ are linearly independent which means that

$$ x_1 r_1 + x_2 r_2 + x_4 r_4 = 0 \iff x_1 = x_2 = x_4 = 0. $$
By the above observation, this also holds of $a_1,a_2,a_4$ so $a_1,a_2,a_4$ are also linearly independent. Do they span the column space? Let's look again at $R$. We immediately have

$$ r_3 = 4r_1 + r_2 \iff 4r_1 + r_2 - r_3 = 0. $$

But this means that we also have

$$ 4a_1 + a_2 - a_3 = 0 \iff a_3 = 4a_1 + a_2. $$

That is, if you are able to write a column of $R$ as a linear combination of the other columns of $R$, this means that the corresponding column of $A$ is the **same** linear combination of the other columns of $A$. In particular, $a_3$ belongs to the span of $a_1,a_2,a_4$ so you have found a basis for the column space.

This obviously generalizes. In the row reduced form, the columns corresponding to the free variables can be immediately expressed in terms of the columns which correspond to the bound variables (which are just the standard basis vectors) which means that in that also in the original matrix, the corresponding columns belong to the span of the other columns. The columns corresponding to the bound variables are linearly independent in $R$ and so they are also linearly independent in $A$.

Comment: You made it much more intuitive and clear, thank you!